# ng-bind-html - how do I make links open in a new window?

Tags: angularjs, ng-bind-html

I'm using ng-bind-html to put up some HTML content on my site.  The problem is if the content has links, the links open in the same window when clicked.  How can I make it open in a new window?

```
<div ng-bind-html="currentElement.content"></div>
```

Comment: What does `currentElement.content` look like? Do they have `target="_blank"` and is the problem that the target attribute is being stripped?

Comment: Links in currentElement.content do not necessarily have target="_blank".  For the ones that don't, is there a way I can force it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

links contained in your currentElement.content should have the attribute target='_blank'

```
<a href="open/me/in/new/window" target="_blank">MyLink</a>
```

if the html content comes from an external source, you could add a filter that parses the html content and adds the target attribute to links

this is a sketch:

```
return angular.element(htmlContent).find('a').attr('target', '_blank');
```

more in details

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="2.1.1" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.3.0-beta.5" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.5/angular.js"></script>
    <script data-require="angular-sanitize@*" data-semver="1.2.13" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.13/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="test" ng-controller="HomeCtrl">
    <h1>Test </h1>
    <div ng-bind-html="myHtml | addTargetBlank"></div>
  </body>

</html>
```

//script.js

```
angular.module('test', ['ngSanitize'])
.filter('addTargetBlank', function(){
  return function(x) {
    var tree = angular.element('<div>'+x+'</div>');//defensively wrap in a div to avoid 'invalid html' exception
    tree.find('a').attr('target', '_blank'); //manipulate the parse tree
    return angular.element('<div>').append(tree).html(); //trick to have a string representation
  }
})

.controller('HomeCtrl', function($scope){
  $scope.myHtml = 'test html content 1 <a href="#">click here</a>, test html content 2 <a href="#">click here</a>, test html content 3 <a href="#">click here</a>';
})
;
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/tpl:JHcBgtJ75fVaqFYQlE4a

Comment: Thanks for the reply Jack.  Links in currentElement.content do not necessarily have 'target="_blank"'.  These are RSS feeds that I'm getting.  I'm looking a way to force it to open in a new window if possible.

Comment: write a filter that parses the html content and adds the target attribute, you'll end up with ng-bind-html="currentElement.content | addTargetBlank"

Comment: The original script will add an extra ``<div>`` to the output HTML which generally is not a problem but does introduce a new element.

A slight modification can be made to avoid the extra `<div>` by changing this from

```return angular.element('<div>').append(tree).html(); //trick to have a string representation```

to just

```return tree.html();```